# Next.js App (pages) error when accessing double slashed path like "https://myapp.com//example" in production

Tags: next.js, routes, url-routing

I have a Next.js App with pages router where I have a [[...index]].tsx page that is supposed to catch all urls, this works on localhost, but when I host the app I get the following error when accessing a double slash url like //example :

> Error: invariant: invalid relative URL, router received //example

I have tried using redirects in next.js config to catch it, but it doesn't work, any idea what I can do to catch this route?

Next version: 13.5.3